# how to transfer tezos to contract

Tags: smartpy

I deployed a contract at babylonnet, source code is https://smartpy.io/demo/index.html?code=eJzVV22L3DYQ_r6_Qvg@xOaM2beQcODSvJAmDRtKbkkox2F0tnatnld2JTl7m5L89owkv0j2ZrMf2tIaDuzRaPTMM8@M9uiuKrlEYoe5rA4ICySqyeQCvV3PVtfP_ny6@v3D6ycf5MtXi98etr@u89XTX_Zk_@KPzfNtOZmkBRYCrepC0mu6_YiLgkhfVNGLkkmOUxlcTRA8F6gWBJFdJQ9IPrwnackzgWSJKKOS4oJ@JtovIxuUJMqYJL4gxSZE5Z4RLkIkc05EXhZZ2EdooqtHOUdqo9@Z1GN2o7gN4yx2IWG9D@@6dGDj_t11CZwv_fEzMECAgENSlZTJLjX4w0BVk1mFOd7ZOVTA5eRkkItm0xUSklO2BUxvgBCcZYBeERqiXS3JZ4R3Zc1kiATdMixrThDmHB_6b9GB2lOZZxzvv4cKYHwinG4O_ldNcoYljjouohQqjSkTvtkYKURBzwkjJANlsJewCzjUEbaEvbPM9s72_Eil0ryaXAK31C6KGyvErTqmirhe8ZUldg6QZWydYYLHzlGhgzq2PwyjoKQYjhCgdale1m_J4TUWuZU3WDclN7IDlVugjRKvHNU03n21YEcDqa@Yu6XZRjdI9Vuak_Q@6Xx9fYhVfjelIBjHOofZqEk@AsGpU3PIObknB3Ocm30DrCDMPzds8FNsubYNGYyoEoRl_hk6gf4pBBltb9QMb3dlWfivMDg12LumGErU9EYroFY2FjS19PwgiTDqq3B6r7XXw1FNOvIorXUdcugxTIoTKCfrj7vswl5aAUwyaoLAcgIG6TO8IxDXW8MH@tj0vBdMVLbaoUnG1GJmIKiFBKepCux7YuYFls_8qM_c8Vkc9Vm0PilhmNPScmpNvvHo5vdNgyuq6ruCpkp1bS_Oj9gWlu1WR7KH_dxYrNkOx@9w5Utw1w19rccr1PoTLmqiTe@tgWK5wDhRX8_MCO4GirKt1CgeDBNl1yVyJsn6ejxKAhdk_Jc3nU69q8Fo00Y91FqC8BiJvhP8aTDGcqeg@I@mD9PpoyAczLYbu8XH_Ae3QfBFg0yb2x6IHPwUOHl7uxq4jLs4zkKUL3yPlXyHi87mteS8UeX0ZvOFZwxaSi4Rk765mkJrNmZT_ZhAg1uqxTG6qUYDoJO6nrKzVkn3xJrFLR5BUuheo1JnGrtB5ieCzH8U5AiZUXfBa8F0l6B1@41@LYj4pk_Kss9vg4jXaqKzjPBWcmGvNMXsY2DVGqdOHYWaQrpse1oUaINpQbLhNPg3wc9DBC1Os9hcA9@BzUqJCCvrbW7d0eMMLD0uvf@MsP4JWo9RuQjPYJJw3jToaf4e_138Eb48egctvQHHyxMcL_@vzbv8kf6XZ@lfcYcAEBMbwk@1a_sfjjnJnQuzbi58A3g@uRs-

It's a multisig wallet contract. I want to deposit some xtz to this contract, so that I can withdraw it through invoking withdraw method by passing multi signature. But, I cannot send xtz to this contract. I use smartpy explorer to send some token, but it failed.
[image]
And then I use tezos-client to send some xtz, but it also failed.
[image]

And, has some way that I can transfer xtz to contract straightlly and no need to pass any param or entry point name.

Comment: After I remove default entry_point from my contract, I also cannot transfer xtz to the new contract KT18uBko1zjuDwqjG9mVcH55aUNnYEJmtHFN. I read the doc at http://tezos.gitlab.io/whitedoc/michelson.html#the-default-entrypoint, so how can I transfer xtz to my contract?

Comment: Ok, I should add defaut entry point explicitly, and then use tezos-client to transfer tezos straightlly without any parameter. Although tezos-client display the Fatal error, it has not effects on results.

Answer (score 2):

Just send xtz to this contract adress as you would do for any other adresss

Answer (score 0):

The default multisig contract cannot receive transactions.
See this question: [How to transfer token to multisig contract](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/how-to-transfer-token-to-multisig-contract)
You have to use a different multisig if you want to allow incoming transactions.